# How to re-size constantly changing text to fit in a div with a fixed width, based on the changing of a <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have text that changes whenever a specific `<select>` is changed to a different option. I need to make this text change font-size based on if it flows to the outside of the div. Here's what I have so far:

```
var autoAdjust = {
    init:function(){
        var eObject = document.getElementById('select');
        eObject.on( "change", autoAdjust.task );
    },
    task:function(){
        var divWidth = jQuery(".containerDiv").width();
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        var fontSize = 16;

        while (text.width() > divWidth){
            text.css("font-size", fontSize -= 0.5);
        }
    }
}
autoAdjust.init();
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/* This makes it so you can measure the text width */
#text{
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How would I make this work?? I feel like I'm over complicating it.

Comment: so font-size should get smaller and smaller? I would recommed using scrolling or letting the div become higher.

Comment: Yes It should, at least until it fits in the div. I don't have room for too much creativity on this one, so modifying the containerDiv is not something I'm allowed to do. @Escobear

Comment: @Shane - at a cursory glance, two problems stick out -- 1). Dom elements don't natively support the .on method, so you'll need to modify your native selector (document.getElementById) to jQuery.  2) It doesn't look like you are specifying the type of unit to increase/decrease the font size by ("px", "em", etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` variable contains a javascript dom object, not a jQuery object. This matters because `.text()` and `.css()` are both jQuery methods and do not work (are undefined) on plain dom objects. Your code should function correctly like so:

```
var autoAdjust = {
    init:function(){
        var eObject = jQuery('select');
        eObject.on( "change", autoAdjust.task );
    },
    task:function(){
        var divWidth = jQuery(".containerDiv").width();
        var text = jQuery("#text");
        var fontSize = 16;

        while (text.width() > divWidth){
            text.css("font-size", "-=0.5");
        }
    }
}
autoAdjust.init();
```

Comment: I tried and it's not working. I even changed my `eObject` to equal `jQuery('select')`, too, just in case.

Comment: Sorry, please observe edit above. "fontSize -= 0.5" needed to be changed to "-=0.5"

Comment: And yes, the change to eObject is necessary also to make the .on method work

Answer (score 1):

Shooting from the hip here, but it looks like there are a couple problems with the snippet.

- Dom elements don't natively support the "on" method.  You'll need to use a library selector to get "on" support (ie jQuery, etc)
- You need to specify the unit type to increase/decrease font size.

See snippet with suggested edits (untested, but the spirit of the edits are evident)

```
<select id="MySelect">
...
</select>

<div class="containerDiv">
   <span id="MyText"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var autoAdjust = {
        init:function(){
            var eObject = $("#MySelect");              // jQuery selector (using ID)
            eObject.on( "change", autoAdjust.task );
        },
        task:function(){
            var divWidth = $(".containerDiv").width(); // jQuery selector (using class)
            var text     = $("#MyText");               // jQuery selector (using ID)
            var fontSize = 16;

            while (text.width() > divWidth){
                text.css("font-size", (fontSize -= 0.5) + "px"); // specify units
            }
        }
    }
    autoAdjust.init();
</script>
```